# Error in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to run unit test whereby I am getting an warning:

'FileName' may not respond to '-failWithException:'

I wanted to know why this warning occurs and how to fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Prevent Build Warning: " NSData may not respond to 'dataWithBase64EncodedString:' "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244213/how-to-prevent-build-warning-nsdata-may-not-respond-to-datawithbase64encoded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever sort of object FileName is, the compiler can't find a method named '-failWithException' in that class. The solution is to go implement that method on that class, or to make sure the compiler can find the header file where it already is implemented.

By the way, it's a warning instead of an error because, unlike for instance Java, Objective-C allows you to manipulate classes at runtime. So while you PROBABLY have a problem there, you don't DEFINITELY have a problem, so the IDE gives you a yellow warning rather than a red error. But in your case, this is almost certainly something you need to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Either the FileName interface does not declare the failWithException: method, or you have not imported the header file in which the interface is declared.